# Querying objects from mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Since I can't explain clearly what I don't understand I'll use an example.
Lets say I have a client application and a server application. The server awaits and when the client sends some keyword to the server so the server knows what should be queried. And lets say that the client requests a product object so the server queries the database and gets back the row that the client needs as a set object. So every time I need some object I need send it to the client in form of a string and then instantiate it ?

Am i missing something ? Isn't it expensive to instantiate objects on every query ?

TIA!

Comment: What you need is to make your web-server response to a product search in the client?

Comment: I am trying to make a desktop app with database and different users that can view some stuff and update them. I don't want to use high level libraries because its for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague and doesn't really ask something but I'll try to give you a generic answer of how to interact between server and client.

When a user request a item in the client, you should provide the client with an API to the server, something like `http://example.com/search?param=test`. The client will use this API in either an AJAX call or a direct call.

The server should parse the param, connect to database, retrieve the requested item and return to client. The most common data types for this exchange are [JSON](http://json.org/) and Plain Text.

The client will then parse either of the data types, generate if required an object from these and finnally show the user the requested data.

If this is not what you need please update your question to ask specifically the issue you have and maybe provide some code where you have the issue and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Server uses custom protocol over TCP. 
If you don't want to use any library you will have to parse TCP messages. MySQL Connector / Python does exactly that - you can look at its source code if wish.